# How to Set focus only to a popup(make all other elements in that page look blur) in metro application?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, microsoft-metro

I am opening a popup in my application i want the user understand clearly that a popup is opened so for that i want to highlight the popup for that i want put the entire focus on the popup when it is opened.

Entire focus on the popup  only indirectly making all other elements/ controls in the page look blur (as it looks when a popup comes in android).

Please let me know how can i work around this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prefer doing in this way ,

Make the grid or whatever ishittestvisbile property to false and make its opacaity to half , then you will automatcally get focus to the popup , after doing whatever operation on popup , then you can disable the popup and you can again set the ishittestvisbile poperty to true and also opacity 1.(this might work as a work around).

Answer (score 0):

take a lot at this.

[ChildWindow](http://www.codekhan.com/2011/05/silverlight-controls-how-to-work-with.html)

[CodePlex ChildWindow](http://childwindow.codeplex.com/)

When you open a child window the parent window get disabled and the child gets focused.
According to your title, this is the behavior you want.

Comment: ChildWindow is not avaliable in metro app development right ? i request you to correct me if i am wrong ?

Comment: http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/c/3062-getting-started-with-c-metro-apps.html yes you're right, i'm sorry.